# Android. Transparent Layout over another layout

Tags: android, layout, transparent

I am developing video player and I need to display SeekBar, current time text view, video length text view over my video view. I also need tho put the into any Layout with transparent background. I have read some topics here, in Stackoverflow, but they did not help in solving my problem. Can anyone help me please! Thank You ver much!
Here is my xml layout for videoplayer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/video_main_container"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <!-- This is Layout that must be in the top of my video view --->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/streams"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#40ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/language_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_screen"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_fullscreen" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- This is layout with seekbar and text views with current time, video file length -->
<!-- I need to show it on the bottom of my video view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:backgroundDimEnabled="true"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scale_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_pause"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scale_type" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/current_time_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/video_length_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
    <!-- This is my VideoView, all controls I must display over it --->
<com.ffmpeg.FFmpegSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_below="@+id/streams"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: better use framelayout

Comment: which layout you want to make transparent.

Comment: I want to make transparent all layouts. My video view must be fullscreen, and other controls must be on the top of it in transparent layouts. Here is example http://i.stack.imgur.com/lnBef.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing your video view after implementing all other things. You should first add your videoView and then SeekBar on it if you are using RelativeLayout.

something like below :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/streams"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#40ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/language_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_screen"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_fullscreen" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- This is layout with seekbar and text views with current time, video file length -->
<!-- I need to show it on the bottom of my video view -->

<com.ffmpeg.FFmpegSurfaceView

    android:layout_below="@+id/streams"
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#33000000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scale_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_pause"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scale_type"
        android:alpha="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_time_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_length_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- This is my VideoView, all controls I must display over it - -->
```

Comment: No, I need to display all these controls on the top of my video view, like on this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/lnBef.jpg

Comment: take a look at the xml I wrote. It's doing the same mate :) replace your custom VideoPlayer with Videoview and also all other things in the RelativeLayout below the ViewView. Try it . it will work

Comment: Thank You, Rudi! I'll try to change layout as You wrote.

Comment: btw what where can I find the FFmpeg player that you are using  ?

Comment: Rudi, You are genius. Code works excellent! Thank You very much!!!! I am using FFmpegPlayer, which You can find on this link  https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg

Comment: Rudi, sorry for disturbing You agian. How can I do the same thing for my Linearlayout with two spinners. I rewrote code according to RealtiveLayout, and changed its alignment to parent top. But this didn't work. Background is not transparent and it is displaying not over video view, but on the top edge of id(((((

Comment: No, now everything is OK. The problem was in Eclipse. I restarted it, and now everything works good!

Comment: great :) sorry i was away, whenever something weird happens just clean the project instead of restarting Eclipse :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new style inside your styles.xml. like:

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

And use it as your activity theme in manifest.somethinh like:

```
        <activity
        android:name="...."
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" 
       ......
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add link to example of what I need in my question. Here is it http://i.stack.imgur.com/lnBef.jpg

Comment: The picture is my video view and text in transparent is an example of transparent layout with seek bar other controls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the actual problem is here, but if you expect those controls to be on top of the  FFmpegSurfaceView (in Z-order), they should occur **after** it in that layout file.

Comment: Yes, I need to display these controls on top of my view.